# Within a Docker image, "Slapd stop" succeeds but slapd is still running

Tags: ldap, docker, openldap

I'm trying to create an openLDAP docker image with custom schema, and I would like to have a working LDAP service before modifying it.

I installed slapd and ldap-utils in my docker image, by putting in the dockerfile:

```
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y slapd ldap-utils
```

At this point, when I open a bash in a new container, `service slapd status` or `/etc/init.d/slapd status` output both "slapd is not running". Indeed, the policy-rc denies the execution of start after the installation of a package.

Well, no problem, `service slapd start` returns OK and starts the slapd service. I can search in my LDAP, modify it, everything is fine.

The problem comes when I want to restart the slapd service. `service slapd restart`, or `service slapd force-reload` or `service slapd stop` and `service slapd start` all fail at the "start" comand. The "stop" command returns OK. However, this time, `service slapd status` returns "slapd is running". Also, I still can search in my LDAP.

To know a bit more about what happened, I tried to start the slapd service with the debug option, as:

```
slapd -h 'ldap:/// ldapi:///' -g openldap -u openldap -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d -d stats
```

Unfortunately, this hangs at "slapd starting" and never finishes.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: You should have a look at a working docker slapd container  like https://github.com/nickstenning/docker-slapd/blob/master/sh you will notice the slapd.sh and the Dockerfile

Comment: Thanks, I did indeed manage to have something working thanks to an already existing image. The bug is still there I cannot use the `service` command, but starting a new container restart the slapd service.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. When being inside the container the only way I find to stop slapd is `pkill slapd`

Nevertheless this is not working with `Dockerfile` and `run pkill slapd`

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same issue in a docker image based on [minideb](https://github.com/bitnami/minideb) (Debian Buster).

When executing `service slapd stop`, the `stop_slapd` shell function of the `/etc/init.d/slapd` script is invoked, which in turn executes this command:

```sh
start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --retry TERM/10 \
  --pidfile "/var/run/slapd/slapd.pid" \
  --exec /usr/sbin/slapd 2>&1
```

When you execute this command in a root shell and omit the `--quiet` flag the following error is shown:

```sh
root@4d1b74229670:/# start-stop-daemon --stop --oknodo --retry TERM/10 --pidfile /var/run/slapd/slapd.pid --exec /usr/sbin/slapd
No /usr/sbin/slapd found running; none killed.
```

The `/var/run/slapd/slapd.pid` file exists, the `/usr/sbin/slapd` executable path is correct too and the process is visible like this:

```sh
root@4d1b74229670:/# ps -efww | grep slapd
openldap   764     1  0 20:13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/slapd -h ldap:/// ldapi:/// -g openldap -u openldap -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d
root       779     1  0 20:22 pts/0    00:00:00 grep slapd
```

To work around this I changed the `stop_slapd` in `/etc/init.d/slapd` function and replaced `--exec $SLAPD` with `--name slapd`:

```sh
stop_slapd() {
        reason="`start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --retry TERM/10 \
                --pidfile "$SLAPD_PIDFILE" \
                --name slapd 2>&1`"
}
```

I applied the change using [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html):

```sh
sed -i 's/--exec $SLAPD 2/--name slapd 2/' /etc/init.d/slapd
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to fix the issue:

```
SLAPD_PID=$(cat /run/slapd/slapd.pid)
kill -15 $SLAPD_PID
while [ -e /proc/$SLAPD_PID ]; do sleep 0.1; done # wait until slapd is terminated
```

Answer (score 0):

this one worked for me, take in mind im using an `ubuntu:22.04` image

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN echo 'slapd/root_password password password' | debconf-set-selections && \
    echo 'slapd/root_password_again password password' | debconf-set-selections && \
    apt install -y slapd ldap-utils
```